# format an xml file with no root node in linux

Tags: xml, linux, xslt, format

I tried to format the below XML using `xmllint --format xmlfilename` with no luck since the file does not have a root node.

As a test I did put a root node and the XML file was formatted successfully.

How can I format this file without a root node?

```
<connection_param>
    <mlc_props_file>
        <file_full_path>./fs/public/mxres/mxmlc/mlc_properties.mxres</file_full_path>
    </mlc_props_file>
</connection_param>

<login group="CONFIG" password="00100020004100470016" user="CONFIG"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can incorporate that content into a "wrapper" XML file that includes it's content using an [external entity](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-external-ent) reference.

In the example below, it assumes that your content is the `fragment.xml` file and the "wrapper" XML is in the same directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE wrapper [
  <!ENTITY content SYSTEM "fragment.xml">
]>
<wrapper>
    &content;
</wrapper>
```

Then parse/transform the "wrapper" XML file in order to parse/format the content.

Answer (score 2):

Use tidy:

```
echo '
<connection_param>
<mlc_props_file>
<file_full_path>./fs/public/mxres/mxmlc/mlc_properties.mxres</file_full_path>
</mlc_props_file>
</connection_param>
<login group="CONFIG" password="00100020004100470016" user="CONFIG"/>
'| tidy -xml -qi
```

Output:

```
<connection_param>
  <mlc_props_file>
    <file_full_path>
    ./fs/public/mxres/mxmlc/mlc_properties.mxres</file_full_path>
  </mlc_props_file>
</connection_param>
<login group="CONFIG" password="00100020004100470016"
user="CONFIG" />
```